# Django staticfiles

Tags: django

Возникла проблема с статическими файлами, пишу `{% load staticfiles %}`, а также путь: `{% static '/static/css/default.css' %}`.
Но когда выполняю команду `runserver`, и подключаюсь через Chrome, у меня голый сайт, без статики. В настройках нет никаких проблем, `STATIC_URL`, `STATIC_ROOT` - указаны. Не понимаю в чем проблема, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

В последней версии Django документация рекомендует использовать тег `{% load static %}`. Так же когда указываете url ввиде темплейт тега, он уже использует в качестве корня `STATIC_URL`, по-этому url должен выглядить так: `{% static 'css/default.css' %}`
[Документация по статик файлам](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#static)

Comment: @Thomas все заработало?

Comment: да, все заработало, спасибо еще раз

Comment: @Thomas Пожалуйста, тогда можете отметить ответ, как решенный